# JS - How can I get text from li class="active"?

Tags: javascript

```html
<nav class="pull-left" id="table-nav">
  <ul class="pagination pull-right">
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true">«</span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a></li>
    <li class="active"><a>1</a></li>
    <li><a>2</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true">»</span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I need to get the number from `li` when it is "active".

Comment: `document.querySelector('li.active').textContent`

Answer (score 1):

```js
alert($("li.active a").text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="pull-left" id="table-nav">
  <ul class="pagination pull-right">
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true">«</span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a></li>
    <li class="active"><a>1</a></li>
    <li><a>2</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true">»</span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

use `li.active` selector to find the elem with the class "active". Then use "space" and then "a" selector to find the a child. Then use the `.text()` function to grab the text. If you have jquery, of course...

Comment: Since the OP didn't specify that they're using JQuery, you might want to add a non-JQuery solution (if only for other googlers)

Answer (score 0):

### Pure JavaScript

```
document.querySelector("li.active").textContent
```

returns only the first element within the document that matches the tag `li` which has `"active"` as its `class` attribute value.

When there's the possibility that several are active at the same time, though, you may need something like

```
x = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    console.log(x[i].textContent); // do something with text
}
```

### JQuery

```
$("li.active a").text()
```

returns the values of all such elements, though all at once (so in this example you would get '12' if both *list items* can be `"active"` at the same time.